# Alter Json with SuperObect

Tags: json, delphi, superobject

I'm using SuperObject to work with Json/Delphi
I have a function that take a string and create a var superobject type, I need to check if it has an object (in my case is 'smtp') and if it don't, i create.
The problem is: 'smtp' has children, example smtp.address and I have to create smtp and all its children, but my function doesn't work.

My Code:

```
if js.o['smtp'] = nil then
  js.o['smtp'].S['address']:= 'justATest';
```

Can anyone help me?

I'm using Delphi 2007 with SuperObject Unit

Comment: I know nothing about SuperObject but I would've thought that if js.o['smtp'] = nil then trying to access a member of that (js.o['smtp'].S) is going to give you an access violation?

Comment: not really, 'cause if I create a fake 'smtp' with children, it works

Comment: Then create a fake smtp. What Stuart was saying is that in the code above, you don't create any smtp at all, so *of course* your code fails when it tries to access the `S` member. There is no smtp object at all, so there is not `S` member to access. Create the smtp object, and *then* start setting its properties.

Answer (score 4):

```
if js['smtp'] = nil then
  js.S['smtp.address']:= 'justATest';
```

Comment: @Henri Gourvest: Can you do a favour considering this unanwsered [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7841617/744588) (Pour l'amour du ciel).